# How to find the closest point to the origin in a scatter plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have this scatter plot constructed with ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
  Threshold = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08),
  Number = c(300,200,150, 120, 90, 74, 30,10)
)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Threshold, y = Number)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

I am trying to find the closest point to the origin of the plot, highlight it with a different colour and annotate the value of the `Threshold` corresponding to that point in the plot.

I tried at least coloring it in red but it isn't working, because it's coloring the wrong point (the one nearest to the x axis):

```
df <- data.frame(
  Threshold = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08),
  Number = c(300,200,150, 120, 90, 74, 30,10)
)
closest_point <- df[which.min(df$Threshold^2 + df$Number^2), ]
ggplot(df, aes(x = Threshold, y = Number)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()+
  geom_point(data = closest_point, color = "red", size = 3) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

What I am looking for is basically the minimum vector from the origin. I can't be sure this point from the blue arrow would be it, but it would be something like this:
[image]

Comment: Why do you think that's the wrong point? What point do you think should be highlighted? Note you have very different scales on your x and y axis. If you are calculating euclidian distance, changes in y in the plot area are going to have much larger effect on distance to the origin. Just look at the distance values themselves: `df$Threshold^2 + df$Number^2`

Comment: I'm looking for the point that forms the shortest vector from it to the origin (0,0). I don't know if this terminology is correct, I will try representing it in the image

Comment: That's going to be dependent on the aspect ratio of your actual plot. If you resize the dimensions, a different point might look closer to the origin given the exact same data. Is that really what you want? You aren't interested in a property of the data itself, but a side effect of how it's rendered in the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MrFlick says, you've lost track of the scale of your axes.

The following will rescale your numbers based on their maximum value, and then find the closest point. This works with your example data, but I am not sure if it will always be correct.

```
    df <- data.frame(
  Threshold = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08),
  Number = c(300,200,150, 120, 90, 74, 30,10)
)

df$Threshold_Scaled <- df$Threshold / max(df$Threshold)
df$Number_Scaled <- df$Number / max(df$Number)

closest_point <- df[which.min(df$Threshold_Scaled^2 + df$Number_Scaled^2), ]
```

Comment: Base graphics has the `xinch()` and `yinch()` functions to convert user units to inches.  I know `grid` graphics (used by `ggplot2`) has something similar, but I don't know the details of the calculation.